# Undefined subroutine &main::vars called at

Tags: git, perl

I am trying to checkout a repository with git. I have specified the git repo path and all directory path needed in `.cfg` file. Now I am trying to access that folder path and repo path from `.cfg` file by getting values as hash. I have also verified my code completely up to my understanding with Perl. But I am really tired of this for past two days. The error I am getting is

```
Undefined subroutine &main::vars called at Create_UnitTesting_Environment_and_Ru
n_UnitTestSuites.pl line 28.
```

and sometimes like this

```
Can't call method "vars" on an undefined value at Create_UnitTesting_Environment
_and_Run_UnitTestSuites.pl line 28.
```

I can't figure it out - what I have missed to declare globally. Please anybody here help me resolve this.

```
    use Config::Simple;
    use vars;
    use File::Copy;
    use File::Copy::Recursive qw( dircopy );
    use Git::Repository;
    use Log::StdLog { level => 'all', file => "$0.log" };
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use TryCatch;
    my ( $cfg, $current_dir, %config, $package_path, $installation_path );
    # Load configuration file
    $cfg    = new Config::Simple( 'D:\\Projects\\TeamCity\\LensXRay_V6_with_git_Trigger\\Create_UnitTesting_Environment_and_Run_UnitTestSuites.cfg' );
    # Getting the values as a hash
    #error line no 28
    %config     = $cfg->vars();
    my ($gitrepo_path, $git_checkout_path, $UnitTest_deployment, $UnitTest_bin_path);

$gitrepo_path       = $config{"CFG.gitrepo_path"};
$git_checkout_path  = $config{"CFG.gitcheckout_path"};
$UnitTest_bin_path  = $config{"CFG.UnitTest_bin_path"};
$UnitTest_deployment    = $config{"CFG.UnitTest_deployment"};

CheckoutFromGit();


# print $package_path ."\n". $installation_path . "\n\n\n\n";


sub CheckoutFromGit
{
    print {*STDLOG} info  => "Checking out from GIT...";
        if( -d "$git_checkout_path" )
        {
            try
            {
                my ($work_dir, $git_run, $msg);

                $work_dir   =  "$git_checkout_path";

                $git_run    = Git::Repository->new( work_tree=>$work_dir );

                print {*STDLOG} info  => "Checking out ". $gitrepo_path . "...";

                print {*STDLOG} info  => "$msg";


                print {*STDLOG} info  => "$msg";
            }
            catch { print {*STDLOG} error  => "Checking out $gitrepo_path failed"; die "Checking out $gitrepo_path.git failed"; }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                my ($git_url, $work_dir);
                chdir $git_checkout_path;


                $git_url = "$gitrepo_path.git";
                $work_dir = "$git_checkout_path/$gitrepo_path";             

                my $msg = Git::Repository->run(clone=>$git_url=>$work_dir);
                print {*STDLOG} info  => "Cloning $gitrepo_path.git " . $msg;
            }
            catch { print {*STDLOG} error  => "Cloning $gitrepo_path.git failed"; die "Cloning $gitrepo_path.git failed"; }
        }

    print {*STDLOG} info  => "Checked out Successfully";
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a `use vars` without a list of variable names? Maybe you should use `our` instead &ndash; if you have something to declare globally. Also, which line is line 28? Please mark that. And as a suggestion, use Try::Tiny over TryCatch as it's much more lightweight.

Comment: I have mentioned that error line no 28 there: also as per your suggestion when I am using ours I am getting error like   Undefined subroutine &main::ours called at Create_UnitTesting_Environment_and_Ru
n_UnitTestSuites.pl line 28.
I dont know what to do :( @sim

Comment: Your `$cfg` is undef, which means the call to `new Config::Simple` fails. Add an `or die $!` to that line and see what happens. And forget the part of `our`, you misunderstood that. Lets focus on the problem and not make more of them.

Comment: Thank you @Alblue for correcting my question

Comment: Hi @ Sim,
I have changed my code like 

`# Load configuration file
$cfg  = new Config::Simple( 'D:\\Projects\\TeamCity\\LensXRay_V6_with_git_Trigger\\Create_UnitTesting_Environment_and_Run_UnitTestSuites.cfg' ) or die ("$\n");
# Getting the values as a hash
%config  = $cfg.vars() ;`


Now also I am getting error like:
Undefined subroutine &main::vars called at Create_UnitTesting_Environment_and_Run_UnitTestSuites.pl at line 28

What is that subroutine I have missed to define ? Please correct me if I hv got anything wrong here :(

Comment: Hi @ sim.. 
It is working after I have added `or die ("$\n");` in that line . But my logic not checking out the repo from git it fails and showing error like 
` Checking out gitrepopath.git failed ` :(

Comment: You want `$!`, not `$`, and there is a difference in a `die` call with and without `"\n"` at the end. I still don't get exactly what is going on here. Please [edit] the question, update it with the latest version of your code and write out a clear question about what the problem is.